# How to detect broken rosbag files

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users,

I've recorded plenty rosbag files during a testrun with a 1min split and lz4 compression.
Afterwards some of the data got corrupted (by the harddrive, not an error with rosbag).
When playing the rosbag files, it works and starts normally, but if rosbag hits a broken file, I get the following msg:

```
ROSLZ4_DATA_ERROR: malformed data to decompress
```

I now want to identify the broken rosbag-files and either try to fix them or if they are not fixable, delete them.
But I don't find a way to identify these broken files, does anybody know a way?

My first thought was to use "rosbag check", but this seems not to be intended for this use, or is it and I am not able to see this?

Does anybody had a similar problem and does know a solution in the ROS eco-system?

kindly regards
Tobias

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255244/how-to-detect-broken-rosbag-files/) by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 179 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-02-21**:
So you tried all commandline options http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline ?

**Comment by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on 2017-02-22**:
I did not try all options, but I read about all of them, and "rosbag check" was the only one that seemed it might be suitable, but it was not, therefore my question, did I miss something or is there no such command and I have to write a script to play them all and wait for this error?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-02-22**:
If I were in your shoe I'd try all commands. Since you say in the title that you want to detect files with issues, I thought if a command that indicates "something is wrong with this file". E.g. if `rosbag info` returns something wrong or doesn't terminate correctly, then that could meet your needs.

**Comment by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on 2017-02-22**:
The files only create problems when they are played and even then only when there are subscriber on the topics :( I wrote a script to play them one after another and display the faulty bag files.

**Comment by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on 2017-02-22**:
The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 0 35`; do
  echo $i
  if [[ -n $( rosbag play -i [cds][aew]*_$i.bag --clock 2>&1 > /dev/null ) ]]; then
    echo [cds][aew]*_$i.bag
  fi  
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since there does not seem to be a solution within the ROS eco system, I wrote a script that uses rosbag decompress to go though all bag-files, detects which are broken and then reindexes them.

```
#!/bin/bash
decompressed_bags=/media/tneumann/fd783860-83b8-4729-8ea5-eee3e08bb9c5/trash/
reindexed_bags=/media/tneumann/fd783860-83b8-4729-8ea5-eee3e08bb9c5/reindexed/
broken_bags=""
for bag in *.bag; do
  if [[ -n $( rosbag decompress --output-dir=$decompressed_bags $bag 2>&1 > /dev/null ) ]]; then
    echo $bag
    broken_bags="$broken_bags $bag"
  fi  
  rm ${decompressed_bags}/${bag}
done

echo -e "Broken bag files:\n $broken_bags\nStart reindexing\n"
mkdir broken/

for bag in $broken_bags; do
  mv $bag broken/
  rosbag reindex --output-dir=$reindexed_bags broken/$bag
done
```

This is of course not my preferred solution but it works, if your bag-files are not compress this might not work, you can try to use "rosbag play -i" instead, but this just triggers an error if you also listen on the published topics.

regards
Tobias

---

Originally posted by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) with karma: 179 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3